# QueryTimeout Expired Error when SELECT after UPDATE statement run in same ADODB transaction

Tags: mysql, vba, ms-access

Mine is Ms access linked with mySql database

Query Timeout Error occur

-begin ADODB transaction
-1st update statement run
-2nd retrieve that updated record . <---- Alert error in that stage.
-commit ADODB transaction

!Update and select run on same table and same record.
!I don't want to commit between 1st and 2nd.

I think that record locked after updated. I want to unlock it from access VBA if my thought is right. If not Please help !

Comment: sql or mySql? they are not the same thing.

Comment: @braX sorry mysql